# ¿Por qué dice que ya se definió la variable?

Tags: c++

He hecho una biblioteca llamada `Game` que se incluye a otras bibliotecas para usarse en clases .

El problema es que he creado una lista llamada `player` y `enemy` y el problema es que ya los use con `extern` y me marca que las variables antes dicho ya se declararon.

Necesito saber una manera para que se puedan usar en todas las librerías que desee usar para no agregar mucho en el main. ¿Ocuparé usarlos en un `define`?

Éste es mi código:

```
//Game.h
#pragma once
#include "Object.h"
#include "Draw.h"
#include "Input.h"
#include "Math.h"

extern std::list<Enemy*> enemy;
extern std::list<Player*> player;

//este es el player.h
#pragma once
#include "Game.h"


class Player : public Game{
public:
void start();
void update();
private:
void draw();
void deleteDraw();
};


//enemy.h
#pragma once
#include "Game.h"


class Enemy : public Game{
public:
    void start();
    void update();
private:
    void draw();
    void deleteDraw();

};
```

las funciones se heredan de Game pero ocupo saber porque las listas se re definen

Comment: Una posible solución sería mover las declaraciones de las listas player y enemy a un archivo de implementación (.cpp), en lugar de tenerlas en el archivo de cabecera (.h). Luego puedes incluir ese archivo .cpp donde necesites usar las listas

Comment: ya hice un cpp y sigue el error de redefinicion

Comment: ya vi como solucionnarlo ya esta hare pruebas

Answer (score 0):

En el archivo .hpp tiene que ir la variable con la palabra clave `extern`

```
// archivo .hpp
#pragma once

#include <string>

class Person{
    std::string name_;
    std::string lastName_;
public:
    Person() = default;
    Person(const std::string &name, const std::string &lastName);
    void print() const;
};

// aqui la variable global con palabra clave extern
extern Person person;
```

Luego en el archivo .c va la instancia del objeto.

```
// archivo .cpp
#include "person.hpp"
#include <iostream>

Person::Person(const std::string &name, const std::string &lastName)
    : name_{name}
    , lastName_{lastName}
{}

void Person::print() const{
    std::cout<<"Name     : "<<name_    <<'\n';
    std::cout<<"Last Name: "<<lastName_<<'\n';
}

// aqui la instanciacion del objeto global
Person person("pepito","perez");
```

y finalmente para usar la variable solo hace falta hacer el include del archivo .h

```
// archivo main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "person.hpp" //--> incluir archivo al main

int main(){
    person.print(); //--> uso de la variable

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: lo eh probado en mi codigo como dijiste ah funcionado sin errores y la cantidad de instancias se comparten gracias bro

Comment: No entiendo, cómo deduces que ese es el problema si @UnProgramadorcualquiera no tiene una variable `Person person;` en su código. ¿De qué me perdí?

Comment: El problema no radica en el tipo de la variable, sino en la forma correcta de declarar, definir y usar una variable global marcada como extern, la clase `Person` es un ejemplo demostrativo, en definitiva es para decirle al compilador que no cree nuevas instancias en el resto de archivos para evitar redefiniciones.